# Module global variable is undefined within a scope of a function

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have switched to modules in JavaScript and now I am experiencing the following issue:
I have a helper `glutils.js` file with a collection of js function. One of the functions looks like this:

```
function updateGLTexture(texture, format, genMipmaps, data)
{
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  //some code  
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

The file is included from the html page like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="gluitls.js"></script>
 <script type="module" src="webgl_test.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Inside `webgl_test.js` I initialize gl context and store it in a global variable:

```
var gl,canvas  = null;
function init()
{
   canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { antialias: false });
   //some more gl related setup and call to:
   //updateGLTexture();
}
```

Then at some point calling `updateGLTexture`  which uses `gl` object to access WebGL API but `gl` is not seen by the scope of the function. It did work before I have switched to modules.What is the elegant way to solve this, without passing `gl` as a param into the helper functions.

Comment: The top level scope of a module is not global scope. It's module scope. The variables declared there are only accessible within that module (although you can export them to make them available to other modules).

Comment: If `updateGLTexture` needs `gl`, it should import it from a module that creates and exports it. (Or they should be in the same module.)

Comment: Guys, please bare with me I am not JS developer ))  I need glutils.js know nothing about the module it is used in. This is a generic collection of function.

Comment: In that case, it should accept `gl` as a parameter rather than relying on a global. You *could* still create `gl` as a global, but it wouldn't be best practice. (You'd do that either by creating it in a non-module, or creating it by assigning to a property of `globalThis`, which creates a global variable: `globalThis.gl = ___`. But I strongly recommend not doing either of those things.)